# Material UI Tooltip - How to show separate messages on hover and on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

Let's say I have a clickable icon and I want to show an explanation of what it does on hover; furthermore, when the icon is clicked, I want the show a message to confirm to the user that the icon's action has indeed been executed (e.g. deleting, copying to clipboard etc.) How do I show one message on hover but a different message on click. Also, how do I make it so that the message on click remains displayed for a second or two even if I'm not hovering the element?

My basic code is:

```
const copyUrlWithParams = () => {
    const newUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?" + queryParameters.toString();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(newUrl);
}
```

```
<Tooltip title={"Copy URL with all parameters to clipboard"}>
    <InsertLinkIcon onClick={() => copyUrlWithParams()} />
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can make the Tooltip message persist for a definite amount of time with Tooltip's ***leaveDelay*** attribute (value in milliseconds). Then, once the URL has been copied to the clipboard, you can set a State variable so your Tooltip element can use to display a different message.

So your copy url method would look like (persistence here is 2000 ms == 2 seconds for the Tooltip message; the *copied* state should stay true for a little bit longer like 2500 ms to avoid overlap):

```
const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

const copyUrlWithParams = () => {
    const newUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?" + queryParameters.toString();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(newUrl);
    setCopied(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopied(false);
    }, 2500);
};
```

With that copied state, your Tooltip can know what message to display and how long to last:

```
<Tooltip title={copied ? "Copied to clipboard!" : "Copy URL with all parameters to clipboard"} leaveDelay={copied ? 2000 : 0}>
    <InsertLinkIcon onClick={() => copyUrlWithParams()} />
</Tooltip>
```